# Proof of inequality (Kantorovich inequality)

Tags: inequality, convergence-divergence

when $y_k \geq 0$ and $ λ_1 \geq λ_2 \geq \cdots \geq λ_n > 0 , \sum_1^n y_k=1$
$$ \frac{y_1}{λ_1} + \frac{y_2}{λ_2} + \cdots + \frac{y_n}{λ_n} \leq \frac{1}{λ_1} + \frac{1}{λ_n} - \frac{λ_1 y_1 + λ_2 y_2 + \cdots + λ_n y_n}{λ_1 λ_n} $$
Is this true?

(I’m reading ‘[Iterative methods for sparse linear systems](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/IterMethBook_2ndEd.pdf)’. This inequality shows up on 143 page under the title ‘Kantorovich inequality’. Maybe this is used to prove the Kantorovich inequality. This is NOT the Kantorovich itself.)

Comment: what exactly is the question? what are yout thoughts? to which version of the inequality do you refer?

Comment: @tired I added some additional information to the question.

Comment: ok thx...the proof is just a formalization of the picture on page 144 right?

Comment: That certainly doesn't look right.  Set $y_{k> 1} = 0$, then the inequality is the same as $y_1 \le 1$ which clearly need not be true.